# Trouble with using Tkinter images

Tags: python, tkinter, pip, python-imaging-library

The code below is supposed to lay out a map and have tag_bind buttons in certain areas. And when the buttons are clicked an icon is supposed to appear near the buttons. Problem is I can't apply more than one image. The image of the icon over the image of the map to be precise.

```
    from tkinter import *
    root = Tk()

    def clicked(event):
        print("pressed")

    def birdYellow(event):
        yellowbutton = canvas1.create_rectangle(50, 10, 100, 60, fill="yellow", outline="black")
        gifbird = PhotoImage(file='bird.gif')
        canvas1.create_image(50, 10, image=gifbird, anchor=NW)

    Title = Label(root, text="Angry Bird Alert", bg="red", fg="white")
    Title.pack()

    canvas1 = Canvas(root, width=825, height=825, bg='black')
    canvas1.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    gif1 = PhotoImage(file='Map1.gif')
    canvas1.create_image(50, 10, image=gif1, anchor=NW)

    buttonBG = canvas1.create_rectangle(160, 152, 260, 170, fill="yellow", outline="black")
    buttonTXT = canvas1.create_text(210, 160, text="Yellow District")
    canvas1.tag_bind(buttonBG, "<Button-1>", birdYellow)
    canvas1.tag_bind(buttonTXT, "<Button-1>", birdYellow)

    root.mainloop()
```

I've found other threads in this site discussing image over an image in tkinter but they all involved the PIL module. And anytime I use it, it says no module found. I have followed instructions on how to fix it but none seemed to work.

Is there any other possible technique to apply multiple images without using PIL?

Using Python 3.6.1 and pip 18.1

Comment: Are you asking about the problems installing a module, or problems in displaying images? You shouldn't be asking two such wildly different questions at once.

Comment: It would be best if you could condense this question down to a [mcve]. If the question is about an image over a canvas, I don't think we need 8 rectangles and 8 text items in addition to the canvas.

Comment: Yup, my bad Bryan. Edited.